# How to setup html within c++ in ubuntu?

Tags: html, c++

I want to design a webpage using C++. 
What are all the packages needed to design it from a C++ file in ubuntu PC?

I also want to know about redirecting the output of a c++ file to a web browser.

Comment: What do you mean by "design"?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm

Comment: @polk design means build. I want to build a website using c++

Comment: @KRUMIA I refered that one but in my var folder there is no www subfolder. I want to know how to install cgi in linux machine

Comment: Then please go to [unix.se], you will find help there. This question is off topic here IMHO.

Comment: That's well to broad for an answer. You'll need a lot of libraries, most of though could be recommended only on the opinion basis. Questions with opinionated answers are off-topic for this site.

Comment: @krumia Do you have any idea about redirecting the output of a c++ to a webpage, any function to do this operation.

Comment: @polk What should I do? Its an assignment for me to get a job.

Comment: This is too broad a question. Do you want to just output some HTML? Or are you looking to write an actual web server? The former is easy in a properly configured server (`std::cout` would do it), the latter is potentially a big application to write.

Comment: @icabod I just want to output some HTML from a C++ file and dont want to write any web server. Can you just elaborate the former one a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to output some HTML from a C++ file and dont want to write any web server.

Assuming you meant `C++ executable` this can be done by simply outputting to a file (which you would give a .html extension).

Something along the lines of [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c4179f10e67ac94):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream htmlfile;
    htmlfile.open ("index.html");
    htmlfile << "<!DOCTYPE html>";
    htmlfile << "<html>";
    htmlfile << "<head>";
    htmlfile << "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">";
    htmlfile << "<title>Title of the document</title>";
    htmlfile << "</head>";
    htmlfile << "<body>";
    htmlfile << "Content of the document.";
    htmlfile << "</body>";
    htmlfile << "</html>";
    htmlfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is not well-formed. Also, please, don't answer questions that should be flagged.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Your name doens't have a valid php extension.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Updated the HTML, and I think there wasn't any real reason to flag this question after the updates and clarifications that were posted in the comments.

Comment: @Prownage Never ever thought of that. That was funny :)